# Image not displaying after clicking in lightbokv2.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I am using lightbox 2.6 my thumbnails are displaying but when i click on image a lightbox appear but it does not display image instead it keep loading the image but does not display it.
my code is-

```
<!doctype html5>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<a href="img/image-2.jpeg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="img/image-2.jpeg"></a>
<a href="img/image-3.jpeg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="img/image-3.jpeg"></a>
<a href="img/image-4.jpeg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="img/image-4.jpeg"></a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firefox Firebug or Opera Dragonfly to check if big images are exist and are accessible. Also check error console.

Usage of different extension (jpg and jpeg) is intentional?

Comment: sorry for this post I made a terrible mistake.